Detect Button Press in Tab Page winapi C++
i am trying to Detect a Button Press in a Tab Page in visual c++
i tried making the tab control a subclass but the tabs disappeared!
relevant code for tab control and buttons:
    HWND initTab1(HWND hwndTab) {
        EnumChildWindows(hwndTab /* parent hwnd*/, DestoryChildCallback, NULL);//clear tab control
        HWND hwndButton1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"Visual Studio 2022", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 105, 25, 50, 30, hwndTab, (HMENU)ID_VS2022, hInst, NULL);
        return hwndTab;
    }

    // attempt at subclassing
    LRESULT CALLBACK mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
    {
        if (uMsg == WM_COMMAND)
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            if (wmId == ID_VS2022) {
                ShellExecute(hWnd, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
            } else {
                return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        static HINSTANCE hInstance;
        static HWND hwndTab = 0;
        TCITEM tie;
        RECT rcClient;
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
        icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
        icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
        TCHAR tabLBL1[256];
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            hInstance = ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance;
            hwndTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
 
            tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE;
            tie.iImage = -1;
            wsprintf(tabLBL1, L"IDEs and Text Editors");
            tie.pszText = tabLBL1;
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, 0, &tie);
            wsprintf(tabLBL1, L"tab2");
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTab, 1, &tie);
            ShowWindow(initTab1(hwndTab), TRUE);
            return 0;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }

i am new to C++
if possible could answers please contain code examples

The button sends its click notification to its parent window, which in this case is the TabControl. But where is your subclassing code? There is no call to SetWindowSubclass() in the code shown, so you are not going to receive the notification. But why are you putting a button on a TabControl itself at all, and not on a page within the TabControl? What is your actual goal? Also, why are you destroying all of the children of the TabControl?

when SetWindowSubclass() was called all of the tabs disappeared. also i had to remove the call from the code snippet because stackoverflow was complaining about there being too much code. i am putting the button in the tab control because when i change tabs i can easily remove the elements from the other tabs. i do not know how to add a page within a tab control. my goal is to make an app launcher. i am destroying all of the children in the tab control when the tab is changed because if i do not the elements from tab1 would show on tab2 and vice versa.

"when SetWindowSubclass() was called all of the tabs disappeared" - that is likely because you are not calling DefSubclassProc() for all unhandled messages, only for unhandled WM_COMMAND messages. "also i had to remove the call from the code snippet because stackoverflow was complaining about there being too much code" - showing a single function call would not trigger that. But, if you were posting too much code than you are not following the practices of a [mcve].

"i am putting the button in the tab control because when i change tabs i can easily remove the elements from the other tabs. i do not know how to add a page within a tab control" - that is not how a TabControl should be used. "i do not know how to add a page within a tab control." - put your child controls inside a separate window/frame, and then display that inside the TabControl's display area. Swap visible windows/frames on tab changes. "my goal is to make an app launcher" - then why are you using a TabControl?

calling DefSubclassProc() for other messages worked and fixed it. thanks!

Making the button a child of the tab control will mess up keyboard accessibility, e.g. pressing the Tab key to move between the tab control and the button controls. The button should be a sibling of (or a control child of a sibling of) the tab control

@RaymondChen That's what I thought, too, but the sample code makes the tab "contents" a child of the tab control. Should the sample be changed?

@IInspectable The sample code uses a static control, which is not keyboard accessible, so the issue is moot in that case. Still, the sample sets a bad example, so I'll update it.

@IInspectable Sample has been updated.


i tried making the tab control a subclass but the tabs disappeared!

That is because your mySubClassProc() is not calling DefSubclassProc() for all unhandled messages. You are calling it only for unhandled WM_COMMAND messages.
Move the DefSubclassProc() outside of your if (uMsg == WM_COMMAND) block, eg:
LRESULT CALLBACK mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_COMMAND)
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        if (wmId == ID_VS2022) {
            ShellExecute(hWnd, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
            return 0; // <-- add this!
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // <-- move here!
}

